# Prove or disprove: Exercise 5 Lesson 4 Enderton _Elementary of Set theory_

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Assume that every member of $\mathscr A$ is a transitive set.
>
> (a) Show that $\bigcup \mathscr A$ is a transitive set.
>
> (b) Show that $\bigcap \mathscr A$ is a transitive set (assuming that $\mathscr A$ is non-empty).

I'm going to prove it in MK's frame. My attempt:

(a) Consider

$$x\in\bigcup \mathscr A.$$

By definition, there exists $a\in A$ such that $x\in a$. Let now $z\in x$. Because $a$ is transitive, $z\in a$, so

$$z\in\bigcup \mathscr A$$

and thus $\bigcup\mathscr A$ is a transitive class. (To show that $\bigcup \mathscr A$ is a set we need to assume that $\mathscr A$ is also a set and apply the Axiom of amalgation).

(b) The proof is very similar: if

$$ x\in\bigcap \mathscr A $$

then $x\in a$ for every $a\in \mathscr A$. Now set $z\in x$. Since every $a\in \mathscr A$ is transitive,

$$ z\in a \qquad \forall a\in \mathscr A $$

and hence

$$ z\in \bigcap \mathscr A .$$

However, if $\mathscr A$ is non-empty, then we can assert that $\bigcap \mathscr A$ is a set.

Is the proof right?

I think the proof is correct, but it seems me very easy. I'm not very good at *Set theory* and this is an exercise form Enderton's book. I thought it was going to be more difficult.

Comment: Not everything has to be difficult in life. Sometimes things are just easy. And judging by the stuff you asked so far, I don't know if you're "not very good at set theory", or just chose a source which is not very good at teaching set theory.

Comment: hahahahaha. +1 for your comment. Thanks.